# Double Group Sum

Tags: r, dplyr, melt

Ciao, I have two columns. Every row represents one student. The first column tells what class the student is in. The second column tells if the student passed a exam.

Here is my replicating example.
This is the data I have now:

```
a=c("A","A","A","A","B","B","B","C","C")
b=c(0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,1)
mydata=data.frame(a,b)
names(mydata)=c("CLASS","PASSED")
```

This is the data I seek to attain:

```
a1=c("A","B","C")
b1=c(4,3,2)
c1=c(1,0,2)
mydataWANT=data.frame(a1,b1,c1)
names(mydataWANT)=c("CLASS","SIZE","PASSED")
```

Here is my attempt for the dplyr package

```
mydataWANT <- data.frame(mydata %>% 
  group_by(CLASS,PASSED) %>%
  summarise(N = n()))
```

yet it does not yield the desire output.

Comment: So close.... `mydata %>% 
      group_by(CLASS) %>%
      summarise(N = n(),
                Passed = sum(PASSED))` No need to group by `Passed` because you need that for your calculations.